# Send RegistrationId To Backend

Tags: java, android, google-cloud-messaging

I am following the Client side GCM code on the Android dev site;  I came across this:

```
private void  sendRegistrationIdToBackend() {
    // Your implementation here.
}
```

Now this questions is not WHAT to implement there, I know how to do `httpost`'s and send param's to the server.

My questions is **WHERE** do I send this in my Database?

I am implementing GCM in an app that *already has registered users*, so I have a `users` MySQL table.  Now here are my questions:  From what I have read, do RegistrationId's have a unique relationship with a user?  **If so, can I just put the RegistrationId for the user into a new column in my users table?**  The only issue I see:  What if the user uses the app on multiple *devices*.  So that makes me think my logic is wrong.  And if it is wrong...

..should I just do what I have seen in demos and put registration ID's in their own table -- and if so, **should they be put there with the user Id in the same row** so that a reg Id can be identified to a particular user (not just device)?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The relation between a user and a Registration ID is many-to-many :

- As you realized, if a user has multiple devices, that user would be associated with multiple Registration IDs.
- If on a single device one user logs out and another user logs in, both would be associated with the same Registration ID. In that case, however, you can cancel the association of the Registration ID to the old user before associating it with the new user. This would simplify the relation between a user and a Registration ID to one-to-many.

Given those two points, having a table that contains for each Registration ID a user ID would work. Just don't forget to remove entries from this table when users log out, since when a user logs out in a specific device, the Registration ID that what given to that instance of the app is no longer associated with that user.

Comment: Ok, so that makes sense.  So I think a table with user_id and reg_id would work -- for the multiple device scenario.  I'll mark this correct.

Answer (score 1):

It depends on what your app wants to do:

- If the user will use only one device you can put it in the user table.
- If the user can have many devices and the same notifications should be sent to all of them you can have a list of registration ids for each user (a one to many table).
- If each device will have different notifications you should add a table for the devices, and add the registration id there.

Answer (score 1):

You could also group the registration IDs related to a single user using the notification key.
http://developer.android.com/google/gcm/notifications.html

That way you have one entry per user and you only need to send one message per user, GCM takes care of the rest.